# Excel Mac VBA Loop Through Cells and reset some values

Tags: macos, vba, office-for-mac

I currently have 12 copies of a Workbook - one for each one of our company's locations.  There are multiple columns, and one row for each day of the month.  Every day the Location Manager fills out 2 columns, and the rest are calculated automatically.  There are a few "complicated" users out there who refuse to enter a zero in the second column if there is no amount for that day, and they leave it blank, causing errors across the worksheet.

There will always be a value for each day in column A, so I would like to run a macro when the users click save that will check column A for a value.  If there is a value then that means this day has passed, and there SHOULD be a value in column D (even if it's zero).

To sum this up, if column A is not blank, check column D.  If it is blank, fill it in with a zero.  If it is not blank, the user entered a value, so we can then move on.  When it gets to a cell in column A that is blank, just quit the entire process.

I've been browsing the Internet for a few days trying to figure this out, and here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim curCell As Range
  'Labor Flow Sheet'.Select

  For Each curCell in Range(A1:D31)
    If curCell.Value = "" Then
     <???????>
    End If
  Next curCell
End Sub
```

I've set the range to the entire area, however I'm not sure how to know that the loop is only going to check column A.  Should the range be (A1:A31) instead?  Then how do I tell it to skip over in the same row to column D to check that value?

I truly appreciate anyone's help in advance.  I hope to be of some help in this community answering other questions wherever I can as well!

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get a chance to test this but it should work all you will have to do is add your own workbook & sheet name.

```
Sub test()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim X As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Ws = Workbooks("").Sheets("Sheet1") ' add your workbook here

For X = 1 To Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Not Ws.Cells(X, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
    If Ws.Cells(X, 4).Value = vbNullString Then      
    Ws.Cells(X, 4).Value = "0"        
    End If        
ElseIf Ws.Cells(X, 1) = vbNullString Then        
    Exit Sub    
End If
Next X

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Depending on the size of your workbook i think it is worth disabling screen updating but its not a necessity also using 
VbNullString is better than "" as this take up no memory.

Hope it helps,

Tom

Comment: Thanks so much Tom! Thats the direction I needed!  Can you tell me how to have it not start until row 5?  I have some header information in rows 1-4 that I want to bypass.  Thanks so much again!

Comment: no problem, if you change X = 1 to X = 5 on line 10 this will start the loop at row 5.